# how can I convert this SQL statement with nested IN clauses to a JOIN format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the very simplified versions of my three tables.

**Schools_Subjects Table**

| SchoolId | SubjectId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 |

The above table contains only parent subject IDs.

**Subjects Table**

| SubjectId | Name | ParentSubjectId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Science | {NULL} |
| 2 | Mathematics | {NULL} |
| 3 | Biology | 1 |
| 4 | Physics | 1 |
| 5 | Chemistry | 1 |
| 6 | History | {NULL} |
| 7 | Elementary Math | 2 |
| 8 | Calculus | 2 |

**Questions Table**

| QuestionId | Text | SubjectId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | What is 2 + 2 | 7 |
| 2 | Tell me the fastest animal name | 3 |
| 3 | Salt is composed of which two elements | 5 |
| 4 | How to divide 6 apples among 3 students | 7 |

I want to fetch all the questions given a (*or multiple*) school ID. For example for `schoolId:5`, I have the below SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Questions 
WHERE  SubjectId IN (
           SELECT SubjectId 
           FROM   Subjects 
           WHERE  ParentSubjectId IN (
               SELECT SubjectId 
               FROM   Schools_Subjects 
               WHERE SchoolId = 5
           )
       )
```

My above query works but I want to change it into a `JOIN` format query.

I work on SQL Server, but a ANSI-SQL query will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the tags to specify your dbms and version. Also, add the expected result (in table format) and an explanation why you expect those rows...

Comment: Figure out the key column relationships. Write the inner joins.

Comment: On a side note: With your two levels of subjects you may consider to have separate tables for main subjects and sub subjects, as your query suggests the school table must only contain main subjects and the question table must only contain sub subjects. This can only be guaranteed to be the case with separate tables and separate foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

If using Mysql:

```
SELECT Q.* 
FROM   Questions Q
JOIN (
      SELECT S.SubjectId 
      FROM  Subjects S 
      JOIN  Schools_Subjects SS
      ON  S.ParentSubjectId = SS.SubjectId AND SS.SchoolId = 5
      ) t1
ON Q.SubjectID = t1.SubjectId

 QuestionId                                   Text SubjectId  X
1          2        Tell me the fastest animal name         3 NA
2          3 Salt is composed of which two elements         5 NA
```

Which is the same results produced by your code